# Building an Intrusion Detection System using fuzzy logic

Tags: data-mining, fuzzy-logic, intrusion-detection

I want to develop an Intrusion Detection System (IDS) that might be used with one of the KDD datasets. In the present case, my dataset has 42 attributes and more than 4,000,000 rows of data.

I am trying to build my IDS using fuzzy association rules, hence my question: What is actually considered as the best tool for fuzzy logic in this context?

Answer (score 0):

Fuzzy association rule algorithms are often extensions of normal association rule algorithms like [Apriori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm) and [FP-growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning#FP-growth_algorithm) in order to model uncertainty using probability ranges. I thus assume that your data consists of quite uncertain measurements and therefore you want to group the measurements in more general ranges like e.g. 'low'/'medium'/'high'. From there on you can use any normal association rule algorithm to find the rules for your IDS (I'd suggest FP-growth as it has lower complexity than Apriori for large data sets).